# The build tools for v143 cannot be found

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, wdk

I'm using visual studio 2019, and I'm developing a kernel driver that requires build tools v143, but I cannot get it because I'm on visual studio 2019 with build tools v142. However if I switch to visual studio 2022, I have the v143 build tools, but the windows driver kit isn't available to the public yet.